# Getting divs with same class name in a div

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say we have this code:

```
<div id='m1'>

<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>

</div>
<div id='m2'>

<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>

</div>
```

How can i get divs with class 'c' that are in div with id 'm1'? And then set them some css settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#m1 div.c {
    /* Properties here ... */
}
```

This will apply the properties to all `class="c"` `div`s within a `div` which itself has `id="m1"`.

If you're asking for how to *get* them with Javascript, you can use any library that bundles a CSS-type selector library (like Sizzle!) to do this easily.

For example, in JQuery:

```
$("div#m1 div.c").style(/* something */);
```

Or in Dojo:

```
dojo.style(dojo.query("div#m1 div.c"), /* something */);
```

Comment: The question is tagged with JavaScript, not CSS, I think he wanted to select it in JS and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var m1Div = document.getElementById("m1");
var cDivs = m1Div.getElementsByClassName("c");

for(i = 0; i < cDivs.length; i++)
{
    //apply css attributes to cDivs[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/1696/get-elements-by-class-name/) will fetch an array of all the elements under a particular tag that have a certain class ID.

```
function getElementsByClassName(classname, node) {
    if(!node) node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);

    return a;
}
```

So your code would be:

```
elementsInM1 = getElementsByClassName('c', 'm1');

if( elementsInM1.length > 0 )
{
    // Loop through, apply styles as you would to normal elements
    // returned by getElementByID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('#m1 > .c').css('color', 'red');
```

You could also do it with pure JavaScript by using [`document.querySelectorAll('#m1 > .c')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) and then looping through each item in the returned node collection and use [`element.setAttribute('color', 'red')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)